# I can't get the image from my directory

Tags: php

I try to get the image that is stored in a folder of my localhost, I do not understand what is the problem, the attribute in JSON IMAGEN get empty, 
I need to convert it here..

```
<?php
        /**
         * Obtiene todas las metas de la base de datos
         */

        const ESTADO = "estado";
        const DATOS = "negocios";
        const MENSAJE = "mensaje";

        const CODIGO_EXITO = 1;
        const CODIGO_FALLO = 2;


        require '../data/Gastos.php';

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {

            // Manejar petición GET
            $negocios = Gastos::getAllNegocios();


            //Definir el tipo de la respuesta

            header('Content-Type: application/json');

            $imagesPath = '/localhost:8888/htdocs/';

            if ($negocios) {

                $datos[ESTADO] = CODIGO_EXITO;

                foreach($negocios as $meta) {
                 // Push an entry in the new array, replacing raw image with base64-encoded
                    $imgFileContents = file_get_contents($imagesPath.'/'.$meta['IMAGEN']);
                    $datos["negocios"][] = array(
                    'IDNEGOCIO'     => $meta['IDNEGOCIO'],
                    'NOMBREIMAGEN'  => $meta['NOMBREIMAGEN'],
                    'IMAGEN' => base64_encode($imgFileContents),
                    'NOMBRENEGOCIO'     => $meta['NOMBRENEGOCIO'],
                    'DESCRIPCION'     => $meta['DESCRIPCION'],
                );

                }


                print json_encode($datos,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            } else {
                print json_encode(array(
                    ESTADO => CODIGO_FALLO,
                    MENSAJE => "Ha ocurrido un error"
                ));
            }
        }
?>
```

Get empty in JSON

> {"estado":1,"negocios":[{"IDNEGOCIO":"1","NOMBREIMAGEN":"img_1","IMAGEN":"","NOMBRENEGOCIO":"YARYAS","DESCRIPCION":"Descripcion1"},{"IDNEGOCIO":"2","NOMBREIMAGEN":"img_2","IMAGEN":"","NOMBRENEGOCIO":"Skizza","DESCRIPCION":"Descripcion2"}]}

It is the directoy

[image: Directory]

Comment: It looks like you have a malformatted url. Your application is trying to find a folder named `localhost:8888`. Try `$imagesPath = 'http://localhost:8888/htdocs/';`

Comment: Nothing stays the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be because you're $imagesPath URL is pointing to a directory incorrectly. In most localhost setups "htdocs" is already the default directory when travelling to the localhost server, so assuming its a relative URL it should be something like "http://localhost:8888/fotos/" not "http://localhost:8888/htdocs/fotos/".

Try:

```
$imagesPath = 'http://localhost:8888/';
```